# Deserialized Object Has All Values Set to Null

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize JSON into a custom object but all my properties are set to null and not sure what's going on. Does anyone see anything wrong?

JSON Example

```
{
"Keys": [
    {
        "RegistrationKey": "asdfasdfa",
        "ValidationStatus": "Valid",
        "ValidationDescription": null,
        "Properties": [
            {
                "Key": "Guid",
                "Value": "i0asd23165323sdfs68661358"
            }
        ]
    }
 ]
}
```

Here is my Code, where strResponseValid is the JSON above.

```
Keys myDeserializedObjValid = (Keys)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strResponseValid, typeof(Keys));
validationStatusValid = myDeserializedObjValid.ValidationStatus;
```

Here are my classes

```
    public class Keys
    {
        public string RegistrationKey { get; set; }
        public string ValidationStatus { get; set; }
        public string ValidationDescription { get; set; }
        public List<Properties> PropertiesList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Properties
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your JSON has an outer object which contains a collection of Key objects.  The following code works (I tested it):

```
    class KeyWrapper
    {
        public List<Key> Keys { get; set; }
    }

    class Key
    {
        public string RegistrationKey { get; set; }
        public string ValidationStatus { get; set; }
        public string ValidationDescription { get; set; }
        public List<Properties> Properties { get; set; }
    }

    public class Properties
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    public void DeserializeKeys()
    {            
        const string json = @"{""Keys"": 
            [
                {
                    ""RegistrationKey"": ""asdfasdfa"",
                    ""ValidationStatus"": ""Valid"",
                    ""ValidationDescription"": null,
                    ""Properties"": [
                        {
                            ""Key"": ""Guid"",
                            ""Value"": ""i0asd23165323sdfs68661358""
                        }
                    ]
                 }
             ]
         }";

        var keysWrapper = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<KeyWrapper>(json);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for saving so much of my time. The solution proposed works really great

Answer (score 15):

check if the destination type has **internal (or private) set** modifier for those properties, even if the property has public access modifier itself.

```
public class Summary{

     public Class2 Prop1 { get; internal set; }
     public Class1 prop2 { get; set; }

}
```

Solution: remove those explicit internal access modifier and make them writable from outside

Comment: Instead of removing the internal modifiert, one could add the [JsonProperty]-Attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39380844/4792869

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define PropertiesList as a list in the class just call the PropertiesList Class as below.

```
public class Keys
    {
        public string RegistrationKey { get; set; }
        public string ValidationStatus { get; set; }
        public string ValidationDescription { get; set; }
        public PropertiesList  PropertiesList { get; set; }
    }

    public class PropertiesList 
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Then try using the following to deserialize:

```
keys myDeserializedObjValid = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<keys>(strResponseValid);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're defining Keys as just a class, when it's actually a property.

```
public class Response
{
    public Keys Keys { get; set; }
}

public class Keys
{
    public string RegistrationKey { get; set; }
    public string ValidationStatus { get; set; }
    public string ValidationDescription { get; set; }
    public List<Properties> PropertiesList { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

JSON.NET is an opt-in serialization library. The properties in your objects require attributes in order to flag them as being included in the JSON structure.

```cs
public class Keys
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "RegistrationKey")]
    public string RegistrationKey { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ValidationStatus")]
    public string ValidationStatus { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "ValidationDescription")]
    public string ValidationDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Properties")]
    public List<Properties> PropertiesList { get; set; }
}

public class Properties
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Key")]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Also, looking at the structure of your JSON, you'll need one more class to act as the root node and has a "Keys" property that is a collection/array of Key objects.

Comment: I use Json.Net with unmarked properties all the time. Your comment (and @MikeRichards's answer below) appear to be the actual problem.

Comment: You're right. I've always used it as an opt-in library, but that is determined by an attribute on the class.

Comment: that's not true. it's opt out by default ([JsonIgnore] for opt-out)