# JsonConvert failing to deserialize integer and date?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, serialization, json.net

The test that I'm running simply takes a .net object serializes it to a json string. I then take that string and attempt to deserialize it back into a .net object. The string that is being serialized looks good, but for some reason, deserialization is failing on two properties, an int and a DateTime

These are the .net properties being used:

```
public string TokenString { get; set; }
public TokenUsage TokenUsage { get; set; }
public string TokenType { get; set; }
public string UserId { get; set; }
public DateTime Expires { get; private set; }
public int ExpiresIn { get; private set; }
```

And this is the json that is being serialized:

```
{
    "TokenString":"encryptedtoken",
    "TokenUsage":300,
    "TokenType":"Bearer",
    "UserId":"myId",
    "Expires":"2013-07-05T11:28:18.4179133Z",
    "ExpiresIn":3600,
    "IsExpired":false
}
```

And here's the inspector, following deserialization of that very string:

[image]

As you can see, most everything is good. Token usage (an enum) seems to have even deserialized correctly. I'm not doing anything fancy in the serialize/deserialize area. Just `JsonConvert.Serialize(myObject)` and `JsonConvert.Deserialize<MyObject>(jsonString)`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those two fields have private setters.  If you want to use private setters, then you can update your contract resolver to allow this, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4066947/634824).

There are some other techniques described [here](http://daniel.wertheim.se/2010/11/06/json-net-private-setters/).

The easiest of which is to mark your properties with `[JsonProperty]` like this:

```
[JsonProperty]
public DateTime Expires { get; private set; }

[JsonProperty]
public int ExpiresIn { get; private set; }
```

Comment: oh totally spaced that one. Thanks!