# Deserialize Json using ToObject method results in default properties values

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am trying to create a .NET Object from a JObject but I am getting all properties of the Object as defaults (null for string , 0 for int etc.)

I am creating a simple Jobject:

```
var jsonObject = new JObject();
jsonObject.Add("type", "Fiat");
jsonObject.Add("model", 500);
jsonObject.Add("color", "white");
```

The car class is:

```
public class Car
{
  string type {get;set;}
  int model {get ;set;}
  string color {get;set;}            
}
```

The deserialization is here:

```
Car myCar = jsonObject.ToObject<Car>();
```

But the result in run time is default values:
[Run time picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cemda.png)

I would like to know why it is happening and how should I do it properly,

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not defined an access modifier to your properties.
Without explicitly setting the access modifier (e.g: `public protected internal private`) a property will be private.

Newtonsoft.Json requires a public setter in order to set the value of your property.

Try:

```
public class Car
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int model { get; set; }
    public string color { get; set; }
}
```

If having your setters public isn't an option for your. Consider the other options listed in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066947/private-setters-in-json-net).