# C# Newtonsoft JsonConvert can't deserializeDateTime properly

Tags: c#, json, json.net

We have a MVC.Core project where we're having problems deserializing a DateTime value from a string into a DateTime property.

Here's an example:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public RecordStatus RecordStatus { get; set; } = RecordStatus.Active;

    [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; private set; }
}


    string s = @"{""recordStatus"":""Active"",""createdOn"":""2018-03-02T21:39:22.075Z""}";

    JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFZ",
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
        MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore
    };

    TestClass psm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestClass>(s, jsonSettings);
```

The value of psm.CreatedOn is being set to

```
{1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM}
```

I've tried a bunch of different combination of values for the serializer settings with no luck. What am I missing here? I know I'm missing something obvious, but it's on of those days.

Thanks

Comment: what's with the T between the date and time?

Comment: Can you try a date with the following format as in "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"?

Comment: The string formatting of the datetime we're getting as input is not going to change. The datetime is in ISO format.

Comment: "T" is the time designator that precedes the time components of the representation.

Comment: Mark CreatedOn property with [JsonProperty] attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class TestClass
{
    public RecordStatus RecordStatus { get; set; } = RecordStatus.Active;

    [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)]
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Remove the `private` access modifier from the setter for the `CreatedOn` property

Comment: You answered first. I'll mark this as the answer. Told you it was a simple problem.... This what happens after a few days of meetings and trying to get back to actual work.

Comment: @MonkeyWrench actually, Pete answered first.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here isn't the format string, that is just fine (as we can see here):

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("2018-03-02T21:39:22.075Z","yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Yields:

```
02-Mar-18 4:39:22 PM
```

The issue is actually the private setter on `CreatedOn`. If you remove that everything works. In fact, it works with the default serializer settings, so there is no need to do anything with that format string.

If you are set on having a private setter for that field, then I would suggest looking into something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066947/private-setters-in-json-net) to make Json.NET use the private setter.

Comment: Ah yes, that's most likely the issue... Let me check.