# newtonsoft json schema deserialize ValidationError

Tags: c#, json, json.net, jsonschema

Using Newtonsoft.Json.Schema. It seems Newtonsoft's `JsonConvert` cannnot deserialize its own [`ValidationError`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_ValidationError.htm).

Specifically, the following will fail:

```
var dataFile = System.IO.File.ReadlAllText("data.json");
var schemaFile = System.IO.File.ReadlAllText("schema.json");
... // parsing the files
model.IsValid(schema, out IList<Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.ValidationError> ve);
var errors = ve as List<Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.ValidationError>; // <-- this may be a problem?
var resultStr = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errors); // <-- this works as expected, though
var ReSerializedResult = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.ValidationError>>(resultStr);
```

I am getting a valid string for resultStr after the serialization, something like

```
[{\"Message\": \"String 'key' does not match regex pattern ... \", ... }]
```

After Deserializing again, I am getting an array of one item of type Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.ValidationError (the validation result had one error so it's okay), but all its fields are in their default values.

Did anybody else also encounter this?  Is there a way to round-trip a `ValidationError` using Json.NET, or should I open an issue on its [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/issues)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encountering several problems here.

Firstly, [`ValidationError`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_ValidationError.htm) is publicly immutable (i.e. all properties lack public setters) and only has a single constructor, which is [nonparameterized](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_ValidationError__ctor.htm).  Thus third party apps (including Json.NET itself) have no way to populate an instance of this type.

The [reference source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/ValidationError.cs) shows, however, that most of the properties have private setters.  Thus it should be possible to adapt `SisoJsonDefaultContractResolver` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4110232/3744182) by [daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/169388/daniel) to *[Private setters in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4066947/3744182)* to round-trip `ValidationError`.  First define:

```
public class SelectedPrivateSettersContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    HashSet<Type> privateSetterTypes { get; } = new ();
    
    public SelectedPrivateSettersContractResolver(params Type [] types) : this((IEnumerable<Type>)types) { }

    public SelectedPrivateSettersContractResolver(IEnumerable<Type> types) => 
        privateSetterTypes.UnionWith(types ?? throw new ArgumentNullException());

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (!prop.Ignored && prop.Readable && !prop.Writable)
            if (privateSetterTypes.Contains(prop.DeclaringType))            
                if (member is PropertyInfo property)
                    prop.Writable = property.GetSetMethod(true) != null;

        return prop;
    }       
}
```

And now you can do:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new SelectedPrivateSettersContractResolver(typeof(ValidationError)),
};
var resultStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errors, Formatting.Indented, settings);
var ReSerializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ValidationError>>(resultStr, settings);
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cNC57f).

However, while this allows most `ValidationError` properties to be round-tripped successfully, the `Message` property is not.  This second problem arises because, in the current implementation, [`Message`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/blob/81e33127e806f22d13430a4882e9e4e8682c7597/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/ValidationError.cs#L33) has no getter.  Instead it returns the value of a field `_message` which is calculated on demand.  Thus it will be necessary to force serialization of `_message` (and a related field `_extendedMessage`).  A [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) inheriting from `SelectedPrivateSettersContractResolver` can be used to do this:

```
public class ValidationErrorsContractResolver : SelectedPrivateSettersContractResolver
{
    static readonly string [] validationErrorFields = new [] { "_message", "_extendedMessage" };

    public ValidationErrorsContractResolver() : base(typeof(ValidationError)) { }
    
    protected override List<MemberInfo> GetSerializableMembers(Type objectType)
    {
        var list = base.GetSerializableMembers(objectType);
        if (typeof(ValidationError).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
        {
            foreach (var fieldName in validationErrorFields)
                if (objectType.GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic) is var f && f != null)
                    list.Add(f);
        }
        return list;
    }
    
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (prop.DeclaringType == typeof(ValidationError))
        {
            if (validationErrorFields.Contains(prop.UnderlyingName))
            {
                prop.Ignored = false;
                prop.Readable = prop.Writable = true;
            }
        }
        return prop;
    }
    
    protected override JsonObjectContract CreateObjectContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateObjectContract(objectType);
        if (typeof(ValidationError).IsAssignableFrom(objectType))
        {
            // Ensure _message and _extendedMessage are calculated.
            contract.OnSerializingCallbacks.Add((o, c) => { var m = ((ValidationError)o).Message; });
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

And now if you round-trip as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new ValidationErrorsContractResolver(),
};
var resultStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(errors, Formatting.Indented, settings);
var ReSerializedResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ValidationError>>(resultStr, settings);
```

The message is round-tripped successfully.  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/e8VfYj).

Notes:

- Using reflection to force serialization of private fields in this manner is fragile, and might easily break if Newtonsoft were to change the implementation of `ValidationError`.
- You may want to cache and reuse `ValidationErrorsContractResolver` for best performance as recommended in [the documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver).
- You may notice a third problem, namely that the [`Schema`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/jsonschema/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Schema_ValidationError_Schema.htm) property of `ValidationError` is not serialized or deserialized because Newtonsoft have explicitly marked it with `[JsonIgnore]` in the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/blob/81e33127e806f22d13430a4882e9e4e8682c7597/Src/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema/ValidationError.cs#L70).  I suspect they did this to prevent the serialized JSON from becoming excessively bloated.  If you want `Schema` to be round-tripped you can force it to be serialized in `ValidationErrorsContractResolver.CreateProperty()` as follows:

  ```
   protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
   {
       var prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
       if (prop.DeclaringType == typeof(ValidationError))
       {
           if (validationErrorFields.Contains(prop.UnderlyingName) 
               || prop.UnderlyingName == "Schema")
           {
               prop.Ignored = false;
               prop.Readable = prop.Writable = true;
           }
       }
       return prop;
   }
  ```

  However, if you do your JSON will become much more bloated, and if you serialize multiple validation errors, the `JSchema Schema` value will get *duplicated* during deserialization, as it was not saved by reference.

  Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QqbAz9).

Comment: In the words of the great Cpt. Holt, HOT DAMN. Great solution For an extensive research! I agree that relying too much on Reflection to produce the field Message is risky; I would probably use some solution based on a combination of ErrorType and Value. Many Thanks!