# Populating an object with HTTP Post response

Tags: c#, json, httprequest

I am trying to read the result of this Post request...

```
public class Stuff
{
    string token { get; set; }
    string type { get; set; }
    long expires_in { get; set; }
}        

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Stuff result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stuff>(response.Content);
```

I'm getting the correct response but I need to populate the object with the content.

`response.Content` is three values that match the names I'm using.

But result ends up `null` for those three values (`0` for the `long`). Shouldn't it match up and populate the object?

Comment: Just get the result to Var before map it into the stuff, and check what is inside the response.Content, Like this 
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stuff>(response.Content);

Comment: That still comes back with null values.

Comment: Are you able to share the actual content returned? Also you may want to wrap that in an if response.IsSuccessful

Comment: Am I able to share what?

Comment: response.Content - the actual string value.

Comment: Also the properties will need to be public.

Comment: Added the string

Comment: Oh wait it was the lack of public around the properties!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution here is to make the properties in the class public.

```
public class Stuff
{
    public string token { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public long expires_in { get; set; }
}
```

If however you need/want a private setter you can use the JsonProperty attribute.

```
[JsonProperty]
public string token { get; private set; }
```

More information on this can be found at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066947/private-setters-in-json-net)